# Website hosted on Google Drive not receiving JSONP from another website

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-drive-api

I am developing a website that needs to make JSONP calls to an external database. When I test the following code on my computer, the JSONP calls are successful

```
  $.getJSON("http://api.openchargemap.io/v2/poi/?output=json&distance=" + distBetween + "&latitude=" + x1 + "&longitude=" + y1 + "&distanceunit=miles&maxresults=1&callback=?",function(data){
    alert("Successful!");
    }
});
```

However, when I test this website through Google Drive, the code doesn't work. Google Drive has a service called Editey, which is an HTML, CSS, and JS editor. You can write your code and have it public for anyone to see. When I test my code on this Google Drive host, the alert isn't being called. I am not very familiar with JSON, but does this have something to do with cross-domain calls? If so, what can I do to fix the problem?